# BottomNavigationView shows only one item at a time

Tags: android

I try to use `BottomNavigationView` but have some issues:

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxx.bottomnavigationbartest.BaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="one"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="two"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_three"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="three"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="new"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

If I have only three menu items(without `action_new`) then all looks fine, but when I have four or more items then it looks like this:
[image]

**So, I can see only one menu item in the same time. How can I fix it?**

**UPD:**

build.gradle(Project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

build.gradle(Module):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.1'
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxx.bottomnavigationbartest.BaseActivity">

    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/bnve"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that `BottomNavigationView` has a fixed size of 3. (Hardcoded `mShiftingMode = mMenu.size() > 3`) You can either try to set

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

or disable shifting mode using

```
disableShiftMode()
```

Due several reasons and bugs i highly recommend you to use an external BottomNavigationView which is well tested like [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx).

This does also "fixes" the issue with the shifting animations and enables the use of a ViewPager.

After you have replaced it using BottomNavigationViewEx you can use

```
yourNavigationView.enableShiftingMode(false)
yourNavigationView.enableItemShiftingMode(false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use `BottomNavigationViewEx`, but now I have exactly same problem with it. I did everything as was written [here](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx#importing-to-project)(I used Gradle) but got exactly same result, where I was mistaken?

Comment: Update your code ;-) Then ill take a look and fix it.